# SQL 5 выбор промежутка между двумя колонками

Tags: sql

подскажите как можно выбрать в промежутках между двумя столбцами к примеру

table1

```
id  data1        data2
1   2019-07-01   2019-07-03
2   2019-07-01   2019-07-04
3   2019-07-07   2019-07-21
```

выбрать к примеру дату что входит в промежуток между `data1`  `data2` `2019-07-02` 
в данной выборке нам подходит `id = 1` и `id = 2`

пробовал выборкой

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1
 WHERE 2019-07-02 BETWEEN date1 AND date2
```

но она не дает нужный результат

Comment: *она не дает нужный результат* Ясен пень. `2019-07-02` - это математическое выражение, вычисление коего даёт результат 2010. Необходимо использовать литерал даты либо функцию сборки даты из компонентов. Конкретный вид и формат правильного выражения зависит от используемой СУБД.

Comment: да так и есть спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE '2019-07-02' BETWEEN date1 AND date2
```